# How to add additional parameter to an application's dictionary functions

Tags: macos, dictionary, xcode6, applescript, macos-carbon

We have an application "MyApp" that provides dictionary with suites of methods that can be called via AppleScript. One such method is "save picture" that I can call as:

```
save picture "picfilename.jpg"
```

What I want to do is to add an additional LONG parameter to specify picture resolution, so the call will become:

```
save picture "picfilename.jpg" resolution 300
```

For this to work, I am trying to add a parameter to the .R file that contains the suites of functions.

```
“save picture“,
“saves a picture",
‘SVPC’,
kAESavePict,
typeBoolean,
“Returns TRUE when successful“,
replyRequired, singleItem, notEnumerated, notTightBindingFunction,
    enumsAreConstants, enumListCanRepeat, replyIsValue,
    reserved5, verbEvent, reserved, reserved, reserved,
typePString,
"",
directParamRequired, singleItem, notEnumerated, doesntChangeState, enumsAreConstants, enumListCanRepeat, directParamIsValue, directParamIsTarget,
reserved8,
{
    /* NEW CODE */
    “resolution”,
    ‘RESO’,
    typeInteger,
    "Device Handle",
    optional,
    singleItem,
    notEnumerated,
    reserved, reserved, reserved, reserved,
    reserved, reserved, reserved, reserved,
    reserved, reserved, reserved, reserved,
    reserved
},
```

But the problem is that I get a **Badly formed expression** error during compilation (rez). Any ideas what's the problem in the above statements? When I remove the **NEW CODE** inside brackets then it compiles file.

Comment: Directly modifying .r files is really tricky. Do you have access to the .rsrc (classic MacOS resource) file that originally created this .r file?  [If so, you'd be able to directly edit the 'aete' resource](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rezilla/).  Or, perhaps you have an .sdef (Scripting Definition file) that you can modify...